# How to simulate way_pixels rules in GeoServer like in Mapnik?

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, mapnik, cartocss

Openstreetmap-carto project.mml have a queries like this:

```
way_area/NULLIF(POW(!scale_denominator!*0.001*0.28,2),0) AS way_pixels
```

Do I understand correctly that way_pixels just shows how many times the way_area is greater/less than the SD^2 area? And in code below from CartoCSS styles just mean "render marker if geometry area of a feature less than the SD area by 750 times"?

```
[feature = 'amenity_parking'] {
    [zoom >= 14][way_pixels > 750] {
        marker-file: url('symbols/amenity/parking.svg')
    }
}
```

Can I repeat the same behaviour in the GeoServer?

Comment: can you add a picture to show us what you mean

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to know what that `way_pixels` mean, so here is my conclusion:

The `way_area` is the area in m². The calculation `POW(!scale_denominator!*0.001*0.28,2)` is the area in m² of one pixel (so the unit `m²/Pixel`)
They are divided and so it results in the area in pixels. **So `way_pixels` is the area in pixels** of the object in the map.

The downside of the pixel area is that this value changes on every zoom level, it gets four times that big on the next zoom level. In some rules it would make more sense to use `way_area` directly as this value doesn't change with the zoom level.

Some information I do got from here: [degree Wiki](https://wiki.deegree.org/deegreeWiki/HowToUseScaleHintAndScaleDenominator.html)

Comment: In that case I think the OP can be answered by using the `area` function in the style as that will be in square pixels.

Comment: Square pixels? A pixel itself is a small area with width and height, no square necessary. Pixels are used also for distances, but it's also suitable for areas.